# My Windows Forms program is not finding the 'app.configconnecetion' string

Tags: c#, winforms, connection-string

I am new to Windows Forms and I modified the `app.config` file to have some connection strings, but it never finds it when I use it in code; it retuns null.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <connectionStrings>
            <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=mydatabase;uid=root;" />
        </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

Also I use this code to see if it's pulling something

```
 string val = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MySqlConnectionString"];
```

but `val` is null. Also, under the `system.configuration` stuff, it says that it's obsolete and prompts me to use `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings`, but the [IntelliSense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliSense) does not give me option "ConfigurationManager", I only have `ConfigurationSettings`. I tried typing it and see if the little blue underline came up to include something but nothing comes up.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you're trying to use ***AppSettings*** when it's not in AppSettings.

Also make sure your reference to System.Configuration is correct.

- Go into your project, right click References -> Add Reference -> .NET
  -> Go down to System.Configuration and add it.

You'll need to switch to this:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySqlConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

This should help illustrate the difference between AppSettings and ConnectionStrings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySqlConnectionString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=mydatabase;uid=root;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MyAppSetting" value="Hello World!"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And then from C#:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MyAppSetting"]
```

Comment: Its doesnt give me the option to use ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.. i dont know why

Comment: Go into your project, right click References -> Add Reference -> .NET -> Go down to System.Configuration and add it. It will then resolve ConfigurationManager correctly.

Comment: where do i see that?, i am doing it in visual studio 2010

Comment: There's a "References" folder under your project in the solution explorer panel.